# Das Keyboard 4 keyboard professional

Tags: 12.04

Has anyone encountered any problems / issues with the new Das Keyboard 4 Professional keyboard? I 've read about some software bugs with the USB 3.0 hub and the NKRO feature causing blue screens and I was wondering whether anyone has used this keyboard on an Ubuntu system and might give some feedback.

Comment: A blue screen???  On Ubuntu????

Comment: @Fabby clearly I am not expecting a blue screen on Ubuntu but I am referring to equivalent software glitches.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried Das Keyboard 4 but I have Das Keyboard Ultimate S and Scroll lock key doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04, on Windows it works but not on Ubuntu. Hope this helps somehow.